# How can I show an image in the website of a react application, right after a user uploads it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload

Here's the scenario: a user must upload a file, once he does it, I would want to display it on the page as soon as the server receives it.
I tried conditional rendering but that does not work.

What should I do to make it work? Thanks in advance.

code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

import './App.css'

function App() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState('')

  const submitHandle = (e) => {
    if (!image) {
      console.log('please upload an image')
    } else {
      console.log(e.target)

      e.preventDefault()
      console.log('submitted')
    }
  }

  return (
    <section>
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1>heading one</h1>
          <form onSubmit={submitHandle}>
            <input
              value={image}
              onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.value)}
              type='file'
              accept='image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png'
            />
            <button type='submit'>submit</button>
          </form>
          {image && <img src={image} alt='image' />}
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) of type `file`, its value cannot be set by code.

And to view the image immediately, you'll have to convert it into a string using a [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader);

So we have to create another function `loadImage` and pass in the selected file as it's argument

---

#### Full Code

```
function App() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState('');
  
  const loadImage = (file) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener('load', e => setImage(e.target.result));
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }

  const submitHandle = (e) => {
    if (!image) {
      console.log('please upload an image')
    } else {
      console.log(e.target)

      e.preventDefault()
      console.log('submiited')
    }
  }

  return (
    <section>
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1>heading one</h1>
          <form onSubmit={submitHandle}>
            <input
              onChange={(e) => loadImage(e.target.files[0])}
              type='file'
              accept='image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png'
            />
            <button type='submit'>submit</button>
          </form>
          {image && <img src={image} alt='image' />}
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}
```

Comment: thank u for your answer, however im getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') . when trying to upload an image  .

Comment: now im getting TypeError: reader.readAsDatatURL is not a function